# Public URL to SonarQube snapshot or milestone releases

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

Where can I download the current snapshot build or the latest milestone release of SonarQube?

A bit of background: When experimenting with OpenShift, I used to download the latest snapshop from cloudbees (e.g. from here https://sonarplugins.ci.cloudbees.com/job/sonar/ws/sonar-application/target/sonarqube-5.2-SNAPSHOT.zip). But since SonarQube has moved to [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/SonarSource/sonarqube) this no longer works. Is there any other public maven repository or other URL where I can just download the it? This would be so much more comfortable then building it from source myself :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the shutdown of Codehaus, no more snapshot of SonarQube is available for download. Releases are available from the [download page](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) however.

Open source SonarQube plugins building on Travis require the snapshot version of SonarQube to build their integration tests. To do so, they clone the SQ repository and build it locally before running the ITs.
You can have a look at, for exemple, the [travis.sh](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/travis.sh) of sonar-java to reproduce the setup.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I was hoping for a different answer, though. :-)
When you run release jobs for e.g. milestones (like [this one](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/releases/tag/5.2-M47)) can't you just upload the resulting artifact to github? They provide an [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset) for it and there even is a [maven plugin](https://github.com/jutzig/github-release-plugin).
Building from source is complicated for someone who just wants to try the bleeding edge version.

Comment: I actually tried to pull [sonarqube](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube), then download the `travis.sh` you mentioned, set the `TESTS` variable and call `travis.sh`. The build fails with 

`Failed to execute goal on project sonar-process-monitor: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-process-monitor:jar:5.2-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.sonar:sonar-process:jar:tests:5.2-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Thank you for the snapshot publication suggestion. We'll look into it.

Comment: Did you call the `install` goal when you compiling SonarQube from source with maven?

Comment: Thanks for considering my suggestion.

I tried `mvn install -DskipTests` (for tag 5.2-M48) but it fails in `Web` module: `Error: Cannot find module 'babel-core'`
Are there any prerequisites for the build process?

Comment: 'babel-core' is an NPM module. NPM module repositories are famously unreliable. You can try again it might work this time. `mvn install` is basically what we do on Travis which is barely customized to build SonarQube (only customization is made to run ITs with some specific artifacts added to the maven repository).